# gnuplot to plot muliple data set from a file and group all this bars

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot

I want to plot column 3 and 4 with bars for each data set in the file, data set are identified by multiple newline and are referred using index as show in script below. I can draw this data with "linespoint". My graph looks like [my graph](https://sites.google.com/site/gkumarpatel/_/rsrc/1339163683719/links/sapmple.jpg). But I want to plot data with "boxes" as [I want graph like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O97Lm.png).

x-axis will have column 3 (1,2,3) and y-axis will have column 4, For each value of x (1,2,3) there should be 2 bars, one from index 0 and second from index 1.

Data file looks like:

> 2-100
>
> 2  100 1   3.10    249
>
> 2  100 2   3.41    250
>
> 2  100 4   3.70    249
>
> 3-100
>
> 3  100 1   3.10    252
>
> 3  100 2   3.48    252
>
> 3  100 4   3.72    254

2-100 an 3-100 will be used as title "first row of block and first column", first 4 lines are read as "index o" in script and second 4 lines as "index 1"

script I used:

```
plot \

  "$1" index 0 using 3:4 with boxes fs solid title columnhead(1),\

  "$1" index 1 using 3:4 with boxes fs solid title columnhead(1)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused -- "data set are identified by multiple newline", but that would imply that each line you have up above is a new dataset.  Maybe that's what you meant but I'm having a difficult time understanding what you're trying to achieve.  (I'll read over this another time or two and hopefully be able to figure it out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reformatted your datafile a little bit (at least, if I understood your original question correctly) -- It now looks like:

```
2-100
2 100 1 3.10 249
2 100 2 3.41 250
2 100 4 3.70 249


3-100
3 100 1 3.10 252
3 100 2 3.48 252
3 100 4 3.72 254
```

You *should* be able to format your datafile like this using `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^$/ d'           -e '/[0-9]-100/{x;p;p;x}'               datafile.dat
#     #remove all newlines  #reinsert newlines where appropriate
```

(this assumes that the column heads always start with a number (0-9) and then "-100".  You're re might need to be a little more interesting if your datafile is a little more complicated.

This can be plotted using:

```
set yrange [0:*]
set style fill solid
plot for [i=0:1] 'test2.dat' index i u ($3+i*0.25):4:(0.25) w boxes title columnhead(1)
```

Of course, you can break up the for loop to assign special properties to each plot or whatever...

If you want special labels, you can do this

```
set xtics scale 0,0 format ""
set xtics ("This is at 1" 1, "this is at 2" 2, "this is at 3" 3)
```

before your plot command.

Here's what I get using the above with the png (libgd) terminal:

[image]

Comment: yes, data looks like you edited. See my graph as I plotted(https://sites.google.com/site/gkumarpatel/_/rsrc/1339163683719/links/sapmple.jpg). I just need boxes instead of "linespoints" as shown in (http://i.imgur.com/zAzfv.png). For each value on x-axis (1,2,4) I need two boxes, 1 for first set of data, 1 for second set.

Comment: @user1444593 -- Did you try the gnuplot stuff I posted above?  It creates two boxes at 1, two boxes at 2 and two boxes at 4. with the datafile formatted as I posted above.  I also showed how you can reformat it using `sed` to match what I have above (if that's not how it is already).

Comment: yes, I plotted the stuff u posted. And my data already looks like what "sed" reformats. And this what i get after plotting data (https://sites.google.com/site/gkumarpatel/links/sapmple.jpg).

Comment: @user1444593 Can you repost your new script and the datafile as an edit to your question?  To preserve formatting in SO, you can format the things as code by inserting 4 spaces in front of each line.  (the above posted code works on my machine [gnuplot 4.4, OS X] so I'd like to see what you have that might be causing the discrepancy.)  What version of gnuplot do you have?  what OS?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04 32-bit, gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0.
The script is as :
set terminal postscript eps color enhanced
set output "$1.eps"
set yrange [0:*]
set style fill solid
plot for [i=0:1] '$1' index i u ($3+i*0.25):4:(0.25) w boxes title columnhead(1)

Comment: I still can't reproduce it (even using gnuplot 4.6) -- although I've changed your filenames to not be `$1`.  Do you literally want your output file to be named **$1.eps** or are you assuming $1 will be expanded somehow and passing funny arguments to gnuplot on the commandline?  (that could potentially cause some funny behavior -- although what your seeing isn't what I would expect).  (fyi, gnuplot won't expand variables as $1 or $anything).

Comment: I am actually running this script within a "bash" script and taking filename from commandline, so $1 will be treated as filename(input file as well as output file).

Comment: @GauravKumar : If that's the case, then you'll need to escape the `$3` (or change it to `column(3)`) -- likely that is being replaced with something else (or nothing) which would probably result in the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: even after using file name instead of $1< I'm getting same graph. I only want column 3 at x-axis and column 4 at y axis. What "($3+i*0.25):4:(0.25)" is doing.

Comment: it is modifying the columns.  `u 3:4:(0.25)` would take the 3rd and 4th columns (with a boxwidth of 0.25), however, since your column 3 is repeated, you'd plot your boxes on top of each other (instead of next to each other).  This takes the data in the third column and shifts it by the "index number"*(one box width) so the boxes are next to each other.  `plot for [i=0:1] '$1' index i u (column(3)+i*0.25):4:(0.25) w boxes title columnhead(1)` should work (even in a bash HERE file).